# Show that the following matrix has positive determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

The following is an interview question.

Show that any matrix of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1/2 \\
1/2 & 1/3\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1/2 & 1/3 \\
1/2 & 1/3 & 1/4 \\
1/3 & 1/4 & 1/5 \end{pmatrix}$$

etc. is positive definite.

By induction, it suffices to show that they have positive determinant. But how?

Things I've considered:

- Use multilinearity/row operations
- Factor into $A^t A$
- Do the Cholesky decomposition and notice a pattern
- Guess the minimimal polynomial and observe that all the roots are positive

I can't seem to figure it out though. I'm looking for a solution that you could plausibly come up with in an interview

Note: I have verified for sizes up to $13\times13$ that the determinant is positive using Python, but the matrix starts getting pretty close to singular as it increases in size. (Of course, you wouldn't know that in an interview)